# Extract multiple lines from a file using regular expressions in Python

Tags: regex, python-2.7

```
13:45:09     HEY HOW ARE YOU

             I AM FINE

13:50:10     OK THEN

             BYE
```

I want to extract the lines between 13:45:09 and 13:50:10 (including the blank lines and spaces) using Python and store it in a variable for later use. I don't know which regular expression to use in order to capture all these characters.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a regex language pattern which describes what you want to match:

- start of line, digit, digit, colon, digit, digit, colon, digit, digit
- capture the next bit
- look for all that again to know where to stop

Then regex match it out of the string with the options `M` (MULTILINE) which allows matching the start of line on each/any line, and `S` (SINGLELINE) which allows `.` to carry over line endings. (and `I` (IGNORECASE) because I had it there already but you probably don't need it here).

```
s = """13:45:09 HEY HOW ARE YOU

     I AM FINE

13:50:10 OK THEN

     Bye"""

import re

m = re.search('^\d\d:\d\d:\d\d(.*?)(?=\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)', s, re.I + re.M + re.S)
print(m.groups()[0])
```

Try it online: https://repl.it/D5SB

Comment: Thank you so much, it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You can apply lookbehind assertion to determine the start and lookahead and the end for the end boundry, as shown below:

```
import re

m = re.search('(?<=\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)(.*?)(?=\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)', s, re.DOTALL).group()
print(m)
```